How to pivot_wider to compress all identical column values?
I am trying to construct a time series plot of GDP starting from year 2000.
My dataframe, country_info_merged_plot, contains all countries with different GDP

I tried to plot it, but turned out to be a mess.
ggplot(
  data = country_info_merged_plot,
  mapping = aes(x = Year, y = GDP))+ 
  geom_point()+
  ggtitle("GDP Time Series Graph")


How can I modify my dataframe so that all GDPs in the same year are aggregated? And how to show the trend of GDP?
thank you.

Hi :) Could you please edit your question with a reproducible example (find help here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/10264278 and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will allow us to run your code and propose ideas. Moreover, when you say "aggregated by year", what do you mean? The average, the median? Do you want it per country?

Slay we cant really help without your data, so I would suggest following the links Paul provided and edit your questions accordingly
